# Django Form validation without a form.py

Tags: html, django, forms

Is it possible to do form validation on a field that is created by html only?

In example:

```
  <select class="form-control my_boolean" id="required_courseid" name = "required_course" >
    <option value = ""> Is this a required course? </option>
    <option value = "0"> No  </option>
    <option value = "1"> Yes  </option>
  </select>
```

Before hitting the submit button I want to display an error if the user hasn't selected this option.  Similiar to the .clean function i've read about.

I do have a form created in the html as

`<form action = "{% url 'result' %}" form method = "POST">`

I'm not using a class for the form in form.py since it's all done in the html.  Did I go about this the wrong way, please offer suggestions.

Comment: Use HTML form validation. http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/ or add JS to do it, Django can only validate things *after* you submit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Front end validation is important for a good user experience. You can do it a few different ways, Django doesn't care. In your case add `required` to the select element

```
<select class="form-control my_boolean" id="required_courseid" name = "required_course" required>
```

Here are some resources.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation

http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/

One really important thing: Don't skip back end validation just because you have front end validation. Your front end code can be modified and is therefore not secure. Django forms will help you with the back end validation (which is more important.)

Comment: Thank you Kevin, i figured there was something with HTML I could use.

Comment: Is there a way to customize the message the appears with front end validation?